# Using solar cells to power a USB device

Tags: power-supply, solar-cell, usb-device

I'm wanting to power a USB device through the USB connection with some kind of solar cell arrangement, separating the data and power lines. I currently connect the +5V/GND USB lines to a constant voltage source, and it provides 270mA but this could vary with other configurations.

I'm quite new to solar cells, so getting a bit lost in the basics. If I used something like [this](http://www.selectsolar.co.uk/prod/265/powerfilm-mpt6150-100ma-6v-mini-solar-panel#prod_det_tabs), listed as 100mA at 6V, if I connected that directly to the +5V/GND lines on the USB connector, would the current supplied follow the IV curve at 5V and supply about 110mA? Or should I use some additional components to get a regulated 5V supply?

Assuming this is the case I would need 3 of these in parallel to provide the 270mA required, but then would the cells drive ~330mA through the device instead? Or will the device only draw 270mA from the cells?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Note (obvious but important) that solar panels are completely dependent on illumination: if you set them up pointing at the sun and get your 270ma, then a passing cloud can drop that dramatically. And the sun moving across the sky will also affect that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes I've somewhat simplified the problem here so I can understand the basics first. Most importantly, is the supplied current always going to driven into the USB device? So, if it were to increase I could potentially damage things, or decrease then it would shut off? Also is it necessarily going to drive at 5V or will that shift with illumination conditions too?

Comment: Note that you'll need to have GND connected to the USB port, your device and the solar cell.  i.e. the USB data connection needs GND as a reference since it uses single-ended as well as differential signalling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current is not something you can "force" onto any electrical component (without changing voltage that is). The device being powered will DRAW as much current as it needs, as long as the power source can supply that much current. So first things first ... current is something you design into your power source as a "just in case" factor - always make sure your power supply can provide twice if not three times the amount of current your load requires.

VOLTAGE is simply a difference in potential ... think of 2 volts as holding sledge hammer two feet above the ground and then dropping it on something ... like a kids toy maybe ... whereas 12 volts would be like holding that same hammer 12 feet above that kids toy ...

Which one is going to have more potential to affect the toy?

Yet in electricity, current isn't really a factor when it comes to damage caused by applying too much voltage to a load. Just having too much voltage can do damage - the current isn't really all that relevant since devices DRAW current as needed where as Voltage is something we force onto a component - it's something we apply deliberately knowing that too much will hurt it and too little will piss it off.  :-)

So in your case, applying 6 Volts to something that only wants 5 volts is not smart - at all!

You're better off regulating the solar produced voltage - 6V in your case, but I recommend choosing your solar panels and wiring them up in such a way that they can deliver 12 volts that you regulate down to 5.

So lets say you had two 6 volt solar panels in series and then two more sets of those in parallel ... you would be able to regulate that voltage down with a simple 5V voltage regulator (such as an L7085CV) with a few resistors and caps and you're in business. Keeping the solar provided voltage at 12 or higher gives you enough variance that you'll have more hours in the day from which you can actually draw 5 volts at the needed current.

The voltage regulator will typically consume a volt or more just for itself, but finding one that has a low internal resistance would minimize this. They also typically will only allow a certain amount of current ... but most of the common ones can sustain 1.5 amps which is well beyond what you stated you needed.

Above all, OHMS LAW needs to be your religion when pondering questions like this ... it is the light that will help you understand all of it...

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling I was getting stuck on something really basics about supplies and current draw, this has really helped.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the I-V curve for a solar cell below, the maximum current of a solar cell will only be achievable at zero voltage (the *short-circuit* current), and the maximum current you'll be able to draw at 5v (the USB voltage) will be less than that maximum current.  Therefore, you're right that you'll need three at minimum to power your 270mA load.

[image: I-V curve of a solar cell]

However, another thing you'll have to take into consideration is that the USB specification requires that the voltage be around 5v--if you directly connect the solar panels to the USB lines, you'll get above 6v, which could damage your device.  Therefore, you should use some sort of regulator to ensure that the voltage going to the device is 5v.  The simplest thing would be a 5v low-dropout linear voltage regulator like TI's LM2940 or STMicro's LF50.  A more complicated setup could use a switching regulator, which would allow you to get closer to the maximum power provided by the solar cells, but that won't matter in your case because you can't get 1.35 W out of two of the solar cells anyway.

Edit: Changed example part number to an LDO regulator

Comment: 7805 *requires* about 1.5V headroom, you'd need a low-dropout regulator or even a controlled shunt instead.

Comment: Ah, good point, I'll edit.